# How I remediate buffer overrun problems like this?

Tags: arrays, c, string, security, buffer-overrun

I wanted to limit the number of characters the user enters for a char array name using fgets, but it still allows the user to enter more than the number of characters it is allowed to enter. How I correct this problem? Below is my snippet code:

```
char name[15];
printf("Enter your name: ");
getchar();
fgets(name);
```

Comment: I had to look up the definition of remediate (root word is remedy).

Comment: Why `getchar();`?  If I enter `Fiddling` won't name be `iddling`?

Comment: The `fgets` function takes more arguments than that.

Comment: Your compiler should have rejected this. `fgets(name, sizeof name, stdin);`

Comment: Anyway don't use such penny pinching array sizes. It's not your lunch. `char name[100];`

Comment: That code should not compile with `#include <stdio.h>`. If you did not include that header, you should have gotten some warnings, and honestly that is just asking for trouble.

Comment: by not using dangerous functions. Use safer ones

Comment: You should never, ever use `gets()`.  See the duplicate for details of why and how to avoid it.  The code is curious — presumably the `getchar()` is supposed to read a newline left over by some previous use of `scanf()`.  But there needs to be more checking than is shown, and you never use `gets()`.

Comment: I rolled it back to the original question. Please don't post "moving targets", this isn't an interactive tutorial.

Comment: Oh, bother! The rolled-back question is not using `gets()` but is misusing `fgets()` instead.  Is the duplicate still appropriate enough, or should it be reopened?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler don't you think there are enough `gets()` questions? An answer has appeared anyway.

Comment: @WeatherVane edit made question nonsense

Comment: @WeatherVane: there are too many teachers who still mention `gets()` and don't emphasize that using it is grounds for failing the assignment immediately.  There are a myriad questions using `gets()` on SO, which is a nuisance.  I'm not sure what's best to do?  Closing and deleting the question because of the malformed call to `fgets()` is harsh, too.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler the whole thing seems to have gone pear-shaped. The answer was addressing the use of `gets()`. It's just a poor question, with no MCVE, and no research.

Comment: @Noal99: You have an array of 15 characters.  If you call `fgets()` accurately, you can store up to 13 characters for the actual name, a newline, and a null byte to terminate the string.  If the user types a 14-character name, then the newline will be left in the buffer for the next I/O operation to use.  If the user types a longer name, then the first 14 characters typed will be stored and the rest will be left for the next I/O operation.  You will probably want to zap the newline to a null byte: `name[strcspn(name, "\n")] = '\0';`. _[…continued…]_

Comment: _[…continuation…]_ You likely need to check whether there was a newline to zap — and you probably need to do something about any extraneous characters entered: `int c; while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n') ;` will read and discard characters up to the newline or EOF, but you only do that if there wasn't a newline in the `name` string returned by `fgets()`.  The duplicate question ([Why is `gets()` to dangerous to be used, ever?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1694036/15168)) covers a lot of what I've just said.

Comment: Note that the first version of the question specified `fgets()` in the text and used a mal-formed call to `fgets()` in the code — the length and file stream arguments were missing.  The question was updated by the OP to mention and use `gets()`.  The question was then set back to use `fgets()`, as in the original.  It's a mess!

Answer (score 0):

> I wanted to limit the number of characters the user enters for a char
> array name using gets

You can't. Simply do not use this function. It depreciated and not safe. Use `fgets` instead. Also, check the return value to check if the function did not fail. Basically, you should always check for possible errors.

```
result = fgets(name, sizeof(name), stdin);
if(result) {/* do something */}
else  {/* error handling */}
```

Comment: Sorry to have rolled the question back to the original version before I registered this answer.

Comment: @WeatherVane. My first time using stack overflow. I appreciate all of you for all the answers and recommendations.

Comment: @Noal99 you are welcome, please ask more questions. Happy to see you have now read the introductory material, and perhaps [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)